# Error while deploying app in Anypoint Platform using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, mule, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I m getting below error while deploying app in Cloudhub using Azure DevOps
Below are the target specifications.

JDK version -- 17
Mule Runtime version -- 4.6-java17
Mule Maven plugin version -- 4.1.1

I have added the Java version and releaseChannel tags in pom.xml file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhz5D.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGAXd.png)

Thanks in advance for the help[enter image description here][1]

Manual deployment is working fine, I m getting error only while Azure DevOps.

Comment: It's recommended to share your pipeline definition(`yaml` or screenshot of classic task detail) so that we can check from Azure DevOps side. In addition, there is an error `Java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer`  on your first screenshot which is network error. May i know which agent do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please find the details below: 

Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: ubuntu-22.04
Agent: Hosted Agent
Started: Today at 11:42 AM

Comment: I have added the pipeline definition screenshot in the case above.

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT please read above comment. Please do no suggest to use images for non graphical information.

Comment: Please read  
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @HimanshuKumar, may i know which branch you are building on? And you can follow the sample [here](https://github.com/API1619/azure-pipeline-demo/blob/dev/azure-pipelines.yml) for a check. PS: please don't share yaml content in screenshot, thanks.

Comment: You should provide [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), and the pom.xml and pipeline YAML as text.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.